# Change scoring function in elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, scoring, relevance

I need to retrieve documents in elasticsearch not by the default scoring function used (such as tfidf etc) but just by word frequency or term frequency (not idf etc).
Is there a way to modify it? Can I do it in python?

Comment: Is there some way to only use coordination factor (coord) for scoring and switch off others. i think I only need coordination factor (coord) for my type of search . tfidf is penalizing the terms because they are appearing in all documents.

Comment: What ES version is this? And which word/term you want to get the frequency for?

Answer (score 0):

You  can use the `constant_score` when you just don’t care about TF/IDF

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "constant_score": {
                "query": {
                    "match": {
                        "description": "any word"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want those documents to rank high which match most in terms in the query. if query has 3 same words such as "tin tin tin", then documents with 3 "tin"s should rank higher than those with 2 or 1 "tin" or even 4 or 5 or more "tin". And you can assume that all docs in ES contain this word "tin".

Comment: I'm sorry, the tf/idf will do that but you want another algorithm.

Comment: Is there some way to only use coordination factor (coord) for scoring and switch off others. i think I only need coordination factor (coord)  for my type of search . tfidf is penalizing the terms because they are appearing in all documents.